# $_GET values being stripped by returnUrl (on an authentication server not under my control)

Tags: html, authentication, post, get

**Issue:**

An authentication server (not under my control) is stripping get values after the first from the returnUrl. Is there any way to work around this? (Or around the larger problem as a whole?)

e.g. `http://authentication.corporate.com?returnUrl=http://localserver/addcomment.php?FirstName=Sally&SecondName=Sparrow` redirects as `http://authentication.corporate.com?returnUrl=http://localserver/addcomment.php?FirstName=Sally`, stripping any subsequent $_GET values.

(I am led to believe through my research that the stripping of the $_GET values may be an issue with what the authentication server is doing, but I have no way of getting access to it. If this is the case, is there a workaround? If this is not the case, what am I doing wrong?)

**Context:**

I am writing part of a web application which is to allow users to add comments to documents. The web application must retrieve the user's (correct) corporate username, first name and last name.

I am updating a previous version of this web application which allowed users to add comments in a two-step process.

- **Step 1** After clicking an 'Add Comment' hyperlink, the user is authenticated and a returnUrl value directs them to a page where they may add their comment. `http://authentication.corporate.com?returnUrl=http://localserver/addcomment.php`
- **Step 2** In `addcomment.php` $_POST values have been retrieved (and confirmed as correct) from the authentication server. The user may then enter their comments in a textarea and submit them via `action=post` to a final page which inserts the comment and user information into a database.

I would like to reduce this to a one-step process where the user may type in a comment on the main page. The way I am attempting to do this is by passing the comment as a $_GET value to be returned via the authentication server. e.g. `http://authentication.corporate.com?returnUrl=http://localserver/addcomment.php?FirstName=Sally&SecondName=Sparrow` along with the $_POST values.

Comment: Tried escape/encode char "&"?

Comment: I don't think it needs to be? 

(I tried it and the second $_GET value is still being stripped)

Comment: If you are confident the problem is the authentication server all you can do now is to replace the divider with another character, i.e. "-" instead of "&" and see if you get what you want.

Comment: I don't think I'd go so far as 'confident' - but it certainly seems to be. I can use another delimiting character if necessary but it seems a clumsy way to do things, if there is a more robust workaround that would be ideal.